Hide plain content or make it invisible while leaving the structure
I have a document of exercises ordered with sections/subsections with the solutions below each one.
With this I want to create a document exactly the same but instead of the solution, I want that space blank so they can write the solution on their own. Creating a "fillable" document for them to practise based on my filled documents.
I know phantom hides it leaving the space, but seems to be very limited. Is there a way to do this somehow sistematically so that the sub/sub/sections are not hided but the content inside in blank?
The document is very large so manual and laborious solutions for each sub/sub/section are not very useful. I want to make all blank but sections titles.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

% My beautiful and formatted document with theory and exercises that I want my students to copy through the course
\section{Functions}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Graphs}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Exercise}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
    \frac{de^x}{dx}=e^x
\end{equation}
\subsubsection{Exercise}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Limits}
\subsubsection{Exercise}
\lipsum[1]



% The empty version of it I want to provide them with so they can follow the subject with this document:
% This is "how I want it to look" which is the same as my document but with blank content
\newpage




\section{Functions}
\vspace{7cm}
\subsection{Graphs}
\vspace{7cm}
\subsubsection{Exercise}
\vspace{7cm}
\newpage
\subsubsection{Exercise}
\vspace{7cm}
\subsection{Limits}
\subsubsection{Exercise}
\vspace{7cm}



\end{document} 

Thanks and kind regards

can you provide a minimal working example we can compile in order to help you? a great deal depends on how you have marked up the content. there are several packages which do precisely what you ask: typesetting questions only, questions with spaces, answer keys or questions and answers based on toggles set in the preamble.

I don't understand your objection to hiding but leaving the space.  Are you wanting the white space to not be there at all?

@Teepeemm hmm maybe I misunderstood the question. I thought the objection to \phantom was having to do the markup manually rather than, say, toggling a switch in the preamble.

I'm not sure if I understand your needs correctly and completely, but I'm willing to give it a try,
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}


\ExplSyntaxOn
  \msg_new:nnn { lazaro } { unknow mode }
  {
    Unknow~solution~mode~`#1'.
  }

  \tl_new:N \g__lazaro_solution_mode_tl 

  \NewDocumentCommand{\SetMode}{m}
  {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g__lazaro_solution_mode_tl { #1 }
  }

  \NewDocumentEnvironment{exercises}{+b}
  {\par 
    \noindent\textbf{Exercises.}\par 
    #1
  }{\par}

  \NewDocumentEnvironment{solution}{+b}
  {
    \tl_if_eq:NnTF \g__lazaro_solution_mode_tl { show }
    {
      \par\noindent\textbf{Solution.}\par #1\par 
    }
    {
      \tl_if_eq:NnTF \g__lazaro_solution_mode_tl { hidden }
      {
        \vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 }
        \mode_leave_vertical:
        \skip_vertical:n { \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box }
      }
      {
        \tl_if_eq:NnF \g__lazaro_solution_mode_tl { none }
        {
          \exp_args:NnnV \msg_error:nnn  { lazaro } { unknow mode } \g__lazaro_solution_mode_tl
        }
      }
    }
  }
  {}



  \SetMode{show}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]

\begin{exercises}
  \[
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
  \]
\end{exercises}


\begin{solution}
  \[
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
  \]
\end{solution}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document} 

when use \SetMode{show}, solution will output normally,

\SetMode{hidden}, will hide the solution content, but leave a blank space,

\SetMode{none}, nothing,

\SetMode{<others>}, you will receive an error.
Package lazaro: Unknow solution mode `<others>'.


Honestly, this looks very nice. The only problem is that I dont have the content I want to make "blank" in an environment. But maybe I can do that manually, is not unviable.
Thanks a lot!
